# How to create a three a simple custom progress View?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, thread-sleep

I am working on an app which needs a very simple progress view .What I need is as the activity starts it display three imageView preferably ,three circles at center of the screen,
and a countdown starts with maximum 8 seconds and as the timer counts down the images disappears..

For E.g 1st:

```
                         . . .
```

then after the timer is at 6 sec

```
                           . .
```

and then

```
                            .
```

and finishes.
This is what I exactly want. Please help me .I am new to threads and runnables .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the [`CountdownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which is easier to implement.

Comment: Can u please elaborate that.I am a newbie ?

Comment: @Navdroid Example is already given there. You just need to include your condition in code.

Comment: check the answer given with CountDownTimer.